# PuppeteerSharp throws ChromiumProcessException "Failed to create connection" when launching a browser

Tags: c#, puppeteer-sharp

I'm using PuppeteerSharp to automate Chromium. When I try to launch a new browser, I sometimes get this error:

> PuppeteerSharp.ChromiumProcessException: Failed to create connection

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading PuppeteerSharp. Upgrading from 1.2 to 2.x fixed this for me.

Comment: I've got PuppeteerSharp v2.0.4 and I'm still getting this error. Any other tips to proceed?